# NSSet containing objects with overwritten isEqual

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsset

In my class i overwrite the isEqual

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * customID;

@end
```

I overwrite the isEqual so it checks only the equality of customID

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
        if (self.customID == nil) {
            return NO;
        }
        return [self.customID isEqual:[object customID]];
    }
    return [super isEqual:object];
}
```

Now the `NSSet` is practically a hash table, making it fast to check, if it contains a hash value... thats something we know

but, let imagine this code

```
NSArray * instancesToCheck = ...;
NSArray * allInstances = ...;

for (MyClass * instance in allInstances) {

    if ([instancesToCheck containsObject:instance]) {
        // do smth
    }

}
```

i would like to "optimize" with this one (use a NSSet for membership testing)

```
NSArray * instancesToCheck = ...;
NSArray * allInstances = ...;

NSSet * instancesToCheckAsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:instancesToCheck];

for (MyClass * instance in allInstances) {

    if ([instancesToCheckAsSet containsObject:instance]) {
        // do smth
    }

}
```

**Does the second code provide any performance benefit at all (under the assumption, that there were no duplicates in the array from which it was created, and the instancesToCheck contains different pointers, but some of the objects have the same customID, making isEqual==YES but pointer comparison==NO)?**

*When i looked up the docs, i found out, that the containsObject calls the isEqual, so it has to iterate over all objects anyway*

**What are the performance implications when using NSSet with objects, that overwrite isEqual? Becomes the NSSet less effective then?**

Comment: FYI - if you override `isEqual:` you must also override `hash`. Two objects that are considered "equal" must return the same hash value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MUST overwrite `hash`, if you overwrite `isEqual:` doing otherwise might break the functionality and things might not behave as expected

**Two objects that are considered "equal" must return the same hash value.**

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) {
        if (self.customID == nil) {
            return NO;
        }
        return [self.customID isEqual:[object customID]];
    }
    return [super isEqual:object];
}

// MUST overwrite hash

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return [self.customID hash];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does the second code provide any performance benefit at all

Absolutely. An array must cycle through the array examining every object. A set knows more or less *instantly* whether an object is contained, because it is a hash table. Indeed, this sort of thing is exactly what a set is *for*.

Comment: alright, but if you look at the question more closely, than containsObject calls isEqual, so it has to iterate over all objects anyway, as i don't overwrite the hash (the default hash is the memory address?)

Comment: Well, you _should_ overwrite the hash. They go together. It is assumed that two objects are equal if and only if their hash values are equal. You will break the set if you don't obey that rule.